# Create Url using Flurl Url class and add port

Tags: c#, flurl

What is the correct way to create Url and add port?

This is how I create URL but I do not find any Url method to add port.

`new Url("https://www.myurl.com");`

Should I just enter Port directly into the string like this?

`new Url("https://www.myurl.com:9000");`

Comment: the Url class have a `Port` property so you should be able to `new Url("https://www.myurl.com") { Port = 9000};`

Comment: According to MSDN, you can simply type it in the URL and will be automatically parsed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri?view=net-5.0

Comment: @Carles this question about Flurl.Url class, not System.Uri

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a special way of doing it. It all depends on how you want to read it.

```
var url = new Url("https://www.myurl.com:9000");
```

or

```
var url = new Url("https://www.myurl.com") {Port = 9000};
```

or even

```
var url = new Url
{
    Scheme = "https",
    Host = "www.myurl.com", 
    Port = 9000
};
```

should all be fine.

another way is to use string interpolation in the first example:

```
int port = 9000;    
var url = new Url($"https://www.myurl.com:{port}");
```

Comment: personally i like Flurl because it brings http extension into strings so you can have a simple `string url = "https://www.myurl.com:9000";` and then do `await url.GetAsync();`

Answer (score 0):

the `Url` class have a `Port` property so you should be able to

`new Url("https://www.myurl.com") { Port = 9000};`